# Declaration of function returning a pointer of another function

Tags: c, pointers

(Sorry this is a sample quiz can't use typedef:P) I'm trying to write a declaration for the following function:

A function:

Accepts a pointer points to a function accepts a pointer to int and returns a pointer to int.

Returns a pointer to a function accepts int and returns int.

Here is my code:

```
int (* sigal(int *(*f)(int *)))(int);
```

However, this is a syntactical error. What's the right way to write it?

---

Edited:

The error seems to be there shouldn't be an `f`. I tried both my original code and

`int (* sigal(int *(*)(int *)))(int);`

on http://www.cdecl.org/. The later is passed.

Any explanation on what's the problem?

---

Update:

As 2501 said, the error seems to be a flavor of parser.

Comment: use a sequence of typedef's. This clarifies things a lot.

Comment: Make `typedef` for pointer to function and then use it for function definition.

Comment: This is a typical example of crap code.

Comment: *Sorry this is a sample quiz can't use typedef*   Is the point of this quiz to teach people how **not** to write code?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't like it neither. Guess it's only to test how well students understand the syntax :D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to write that is to use a typedef:

```
typedef int*(*fp)(int*);
typedef int(*fi)(int);

fi function(fp p);
```

The correct way to write this without typedef is:

```
int ( *( function( int*(*p)(int*) ) ) )(int);
```

Comment: Sorry it's a sample quiz from a course which can't use typedef :P. Would you please show me the full version?

Comment: thank you for your answer. But please don't worry it's a sample for mid-term quiz.

Comment: Sorry but I tried your answer in several parsers and still got a syntax error. What's the difference between yours and mine? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the bother. Would you please see my update and make some explanations? Many thanks!

Comment: @spacegoing Don't rely on a single source of Truth.